# Why choose ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 over other linux distros?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, package-management, lts

Trying to white up some notes on why we choose ubuntu over all the other distros out there but it would be good to know what the you guys think is the reason

Does ubuntu 12.04/14.04 LTS have a longer support then other distros?

When a security flaw is found does ubuntu update its package repos faster?

What are the main benefits would you say?

Thanks

Comment: Questions that ask for opinions tend to be considered off topic. ( http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask and http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic for more on this)

Comment: This is not an ask for opinions. OP asked what are benefits of LTS and got an excellent answer.

Comment: "Why choose ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 over other linux distros?" @Pilot6 is a matter of opinion. So is "What are the main benefits would you say? "

Comment: @Pilot6 bad questions can have great answers, that's why there's a "reversal" badge.

Comment: The question is not great, but it is quite common. And the answer gives good base for making a personal decision.

Comment: @Pilot6 some questions are common, but still not welcome here.

Answer (score 5):

Quoted from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

> LTS is an abbreviation for “Long Term Support”.
>
> We produce a new Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server release every six
>   months [diagram below]. That means you'll always have the latest and
>   greatest applications that the open source world has to offer. Ubuntu
>   is designed with security in mind. You get free security updates for
>   at least 9 months on the desktop and server.
>
> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a
>   Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu
>   (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04
>   LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee
>   for the LTS version; we make our very best work available to everyone
>   on the same free terms. Upgrades to new versions of Ubuntu are and
>   always will be free of charge.

Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 are LTS which means it will still have support for 5 years, while others not LTS have support for 9 months only.

[image]

This is the main reason for choosing LTS distros.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/162768/should-you-use-ubuntu-lts-or-upgrade-to-the-latest-release/) for more information about.

**support means:**

- Updates for potential security problems and bugs
- Commercial support from Canonical
- [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/) support

**Now what should you use?**

This depends to your needs. If you want a stable supported version you should use LTS and here 14.04 is preferred if you want new version packages. But If you are looking for trying some new concepts and be up to date with the newest versions you can use non LTS normal versions which is now 15.04 the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer, I know that this more an opinion but its very useful to know what makes ubuntu better then other linux distros

Comment: You are welcome, hope to make it easy to take your choice

Comment: Accept this post as the answer if you wish.